# Can somebody give some product names which are dbms but not rdbms?

Tags: rdbms, database

There are so many products which are rdbms like oracle,mysql,SqlServer etc....
But what about dbms related products?Is foxpro dbms ?

Comment: Related Wikipedia links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbms http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[All these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

Comment: Google bigtable ? It deals with semi-structured  data types.But in case of dbms we have only structured data types.I need purely dbms related product.

Comment: Pick / IBM / Rocket U2 refers to itself as a 'post relational' db. 
Now No-SQL :)

Comment: Get the history here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick_operating_system. Dick Pick was one of the cofounders. Interesting to see how db's have evolved (and why natural code 'fks' were used to avoid joins, but wouldn't dream of using it in 2010.

Answer (score 2):

A growing segment of the non-rdbms market are the [document-oriented databases](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) (disclaimer: some of these are implemented *on top of* an RDBMS underneath, so all aren't "non-RdBMS").

There are *many* databases that aren't RDBMS though, this is just one of the most active alternatives at the moment, so worth noting IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Information Management System (IMS) from IBM: [Record based data model – Hierarchical data model]
Integrated Data Management System(IDMS) from Honeywell [Record based data model – Network data model]

Answer (score -1):

MS-Access is a classical example for DBMS which is not a RDBMS.
Read more on [Difference between dbms and rdbms](http://sqlandplsql.com/2011/11/20/difference-between-dbms-and-rdbms-2/)

Comment: I have to downvote, because this answer is entirely wrong. The "R" is the important thing, and the Relational design is the only important row in that table. And I hate to break it to you, but while Access may not be the greatest DB out there, it **is** relational (enough) to qualify; a better discussion: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/12/22/access_not_relational_myth/